# Australian eVisitor Visa/criminal record

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia, criminal-records

I'm a UK citizen, my dad is an Australian citizen, and I booked flights for February 9, 2024, not realizing that a visa is required to visit Australia.

I applied for the eVisitor visa 2 days ago, with only 8 weeks to go until my flight. Believing that honesty is the best policy, I answered "yes" to the criminal conviction question. When I was 15 years old (17 years ago), I was reprimanded for affray, which wasn't an actual conviction that went to court but more like a caution or warning. As a registered nurse, this does not appear on my DBS check, which is always clear. I'm concerned whether Australia will request a police check, as there is no way I could obtain one in time for my flights. To demonstrate good character, I have uploaded a statement of events, my NMC registration, my most recent DBS check, and a declaration of good character from my employer. Will this suffice, or are they likely to request a police check anyway? My application is still at "received."

I can't believe how much information is required just to visit Australia for 10 days. I wish I had done my research before booking.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may have been a little *too* honest here, since as far as I can tell you we're not actually convicted, and were a minor at the time to boot.  Unfortunately your eVisitor is likely to be automatically refused and you'll need to apply for a regular tourist visa, which likely *will* be granted, but will also take some time.

Comment: just wondering how you get on with this? My husband's in a similar situation having applied for an eVisitor with an old drink driving conviction. Not sure if we'll be able to get an ACRO certificate back in time so wondering if a DBS would help? Thanks, and really hope everything worked out for you!

Answer (score 3):

Honesty is the best thing to apply to anything immigration related

> Will Australia ask for a police check?

It's all [case-dependant](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/meeting-our-requirements/character), we can't know in advance what you will be asked for

> We may ask you to:

> provide a police certificate